# Calculate Full Joint Distribution table

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

There are three nodes, rich, educated, and successful with the stated relationships and probabilities.  How can I calculate the Full Joint Distribution table for for it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Example:

- Start with $1$ million people.
- How many do you expect to be rich? $1000000 \times 0.01 = 10000$
- How many do you expect to be rich but not educated? $10000 \times (1-0.720) = 2800$
- How many do you expect to be rich, not educated, but successful? $2800 \times 0.450=1260$
- What is the joint probability of being rich, not educated, and successful? $\frac{1260}{1000000}=0.00126$

Similarly for all the other cells